# Does USB Gamepad require proprietary driver

Tags: gamepad

Could anyone tell me whether USB wired gamepads are generally automatically detected in Windows 10 or whether they require a proprietary driver? I seem to recall reading reviews which suggest that some gamepads install without the need for additional drivers, have I got that correct.

Looking at a Speedlink RAIT Gamepad Wired but notice it comes with a software driver, is that because it is not straight out the box fully compatible with Windows?

Comment: For which operating system ? Windows ? And which specific gamepad?

Comment: Windows 10 and Speedlink RAIT Gamepad Wired

Comment: Most gamepads will work with the generic usb_hid driver, but any extra functionality like rumble, lights, programmable keys, etc. likely won't work. You will need the proprietary driver for that stuff.

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off-topic on Super User. I removed that.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realiase about not being allowed to ask for hardware recomendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gamepad supports two operating modes: XInput (modern) and DirectInput (legacy, for old games). Only in XInput mode does it work without additional drivers. It defaults to DirectInput.

You can switch between XInput and DirectInput by pressing the "Mode" button for ~3 seconds. It's not clear whether it would remember the last mode after being powered off.

From the [product page](https://www.speedlink.com/RAIT-Gamepad-fuer-PC-PS3-Switch-OLED-rubber-schwarz/SL-650010-BK) FAQ (only in German does it have all information):

> **Wie kann ich zwischen Xinput Modus und Direct Input Modus wechseln?**
> Dazu drücke und halte den Mode Button für ca. 3 Sekunden. (Bitte achte darauf den Modeswitch vor Spielstart vorzunehmen.)
>
> **Was ist Xinput oder Direct Input?**
> Xinput macht aus dem Gamepad eine Xbox Controller mit allen Tastenbelegungen eines Xbox Gamepads. Direct Input ist der Standardmodus des jeweiligen Gamepads und wird durch zusätzliche Treibersoftware unterstützt.

---

Also, to address the possibly implied question: are there any game controllers that work without additional drivers? The answer is yes, all wired game controllers for Xbox One and newer work using built-in drivers on Windows. (Wireless devices also work, but you need a proprietary USB receiver to connect them.)

Answer (score 0):

The Speedlink page has this information:
[RAIT Gamepad - for PC/PS3/Switch/OLED, rubber-black](https://www.speedlink.com/en/RAIT-Gamepad-for-PC-PS3-Switch-OLED-rubber-black/SL-650010-BK)
in the Downloads section:

> - Driver: [Download](https://www.speedlink.com/media/ba/05/a8/1637145478/Speedlink%20RAIT%20wired%20(1).exe)

The answer is positive - this gamepad has a driver (or software).